# How to check if either array values are in an object as key

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check if an array of keys are included in an object without the need of library or some nested loops?

```js
/** Incoming: */
const foo = {do: 1, ray: 1, me: 1};

/** Check for: */
const fields = ['doo', 'foo', 'me'];

/** Convert object keys into array */
const fooArray = Object.keys(foo);

fooArray.includes(fields) // I wish this would work :(
```

Is this the only way?:

```js
fields.map(field => {

  const bool = foo.hasOwnProperty(field);
  // Do something if bool is true

});
```

I want to return `true` if any of the key names inside `fields` are in the object `foo`. I'd rather not doing ant loops if there's a simpler way. Thanks.

Comment: `Object.keys().some(k => fields.includes(k))`

Comment: Any solution would somehow use sort of iteration. Although I'm not sure why that's undesirable.

Comment: @FelixKling also can be inverted as `fields.some(field => field in foo)`.

Comment: Wow! So basically, some sort of loop has to be involved?

Comment: If you want to do something with `n` items then you have to iterate at least `n` times one way or the other.

Comment: @Sylar yes. You have `n` number of items and you want to check them. You have to do it linearly. If it's not a loop, then it'd be recursion but it's the same thing in the end of it - you'd get a `O(n)` algorithm.

Comment: I only need `true` or `false`. Not doing anything with `n` so the loop could break, if true, for speed?

Comment: @Sylar `some`/`every` will exit as soon as possible. However, any iteration is always `O(n)` since you have to potentially evaluate all `n` items. It doesn't matter that you *might* only evaluate a subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and `hasOwnProperty()`:

```js
/** Incoming: */
const foo = {do: 1, ray: 1, me: 1};

/** Check for: */
const fields = ['doo', 'foo', 'me'];

/** Convert object keys into array */
const fooArray = Object.keys(foo);

var res = fields.some(field => foo.hasOwnProperty(field));
console.log(res);
```

If you want the result for each item then use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
/** Incoming: */
const foo = {do: 1, ray: 1, me: 1};

/** Check for: */
const fields = ['doo', 'foo', 'me'];

/** Convert object keys into array */
const fooArray = Object.keys(foo);

var res = fields.map(field => foo.hasOwnProperty(field));
console.log(res);
```